# ruby on rails upgrade asset precompilation failure

Tags: ruby, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-sprockets

I have a rails 4.2 application I am in the process of upgrading from 3.2.  Something is going wrong with asset precomiplation but I'm not sure what I am missing.

```
#Gemfile
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.7.1'
ruby "2.3.3"

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.1.4'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'sprockets-rails', '2.3.3
```

Here is the active_admin.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require select2
//= require active_admin/base
//= require best_in_place
//= require best_in_place.jquery-ui
//= require activeadmin-sortable
```

The asset precompilation fails here

```
$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile
I, [2018-02-28T10:58:20.467128 #6312]  INFO -- : Writing /home/nellis/src/circle2/public/assets/style-6150d2089bcada194fcfda8d38d0046cadfe7a754b6b477226d1b701cda7e197.css.gz
rake aborted!
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery_ujs' with type 'application/javascript'
Checked in these paths: 
  /home/nellis/src/circle2/app/assets/fonts
  /home/nellis/src/circle2/app/assets/images
  /home/nellis/src/circle2/app/assets/javascripts
  /home/nellis/src/circle2/app/assets/stylesheets
  /home/nellis/src/circle2/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /home/nellis/src/circle2/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /home/nellis/src/circle2/public/vendor
/home/nellis/src/circle2/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js:2
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/resolve.rb:65:in `resolve!'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:399:in `resolve'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:207:in `process_require_directive'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:180:in `block in process_directives'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:178:in `each'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:178:in `process_directives'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:83:in `_call'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:68:in `call'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:200:in `dfs'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:134:in `block in find'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:133:in `each'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:133:in `find'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:185:in `compile'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/nellis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
zlib(finalizer): Zlib::GzipWriter object must be closed explicitly.
zlib(finalizer): the stream was freed prematurely.
```

All the questions I read just say run bundle install and make sure the gems are in your Gemfile which they are.

Comment: That's a pretty old version of `jquery-rails`. Maybe it doesn't like to be used in a more recent version of Rails?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say what's going on without knowing more about your configuration, but it might be a loading issue. `jquery-rails` puts the actual `.js` files in `vendor/assets/javascripts`, which might not be in your load path for whatever reason. You might try two things:

First try running the generator that comes with the gem to see if it fixes the paths in the manifest file:

```
rails generate jquery:install #--ui to enable jQuery UI
```

If that doesn't work, and don't want to upgrade `jquery-rails`, you might have to do something like this

```
//= require vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.js
//= require vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js
//= require vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery-ui.js
```

If I were you I would upgrade